# What is the type definition of file payload with multipart/form-data in hapijs?

Tags: typescript, hapi.js, hapi

I am using hapijs with typescript.
I upload file in `multipart/fom-data`. I want to define the type of the `req.payload.file`.
But unfortunately, I couldn't find any documentation to know the type.
here is the result of `console.log(req.payload.file);`

```
Readable {
  _readableState:
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: null,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     paused: true,
     emitClose: true,
     autoDestroy: false,
     destroyed: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _data:
   <Buffer 50 4b 03 04 14 00 06 00 08 00 00 00 21 00 48 41 42 ca 71 01 00 00 b0 06 00 00 13 00 08 02 5b 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 5f 54 79 70 65 73 5d 2e 78 6d 6c 20 ... >,
  _position: 0,
  _encoding: 'utf8',
  hapi:
   { filename: 'file.xlsx',
     headers:
      { 'content-disposition': 'form-data; name="file"; filename="file.xlsx"',
        'content-type':
         'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' } } }
```

I want to make this:

`const file: <ApropriateTypeHere> = req.payload.file;`

so I could see all property inside the `file` as printed in the `console.log()`

Comment: can you show the route config? and are you using `Inert`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://hapi.dev/api/?v=19.1.0#-routeoptionspayloadoutput):

> ...the incoming payload is made available via a Stream.Readable interface.

For which you can find more information in the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable). The typings can be found in [@types/node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node).

Comment: sorry but I still couldn't find appropriate type. I use interface Stream but there is no ._data property on it

Comment: There won't be, you shouldn't be accessing private variables.

Answer (score 0):

Multipart requests combine one or more sets of data into a single body, separated by boundaries.

I think you are looking for

```
    const filename = file.hapi.filename
    console.log(filename )
    const data = file._data
```

then you can do this

```
   fs.writeFile('./upload/' + filename, data, err => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      }
      resolve({ message: 'Upload successfully!' })
    })
```

Comment: I am looking for the type definition. Not how to get the data. I know how to get the data. Yes I am using inert

Comment: @Akza  there is no new definition of  multipart form data in hapijs and I hope you have knowledge of Multipart requests. but there is configuration of payload output 'data', 'stream', 'file' [routeoptionspayloadmultipart](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/API.md#-routeoptionspayloadmultipart)